# How to return the entire request url using silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have website url like, I would like to get full url so that i can pass to social network for sharing purpose

i.e. www.mysite.com/projects?tab=2

I tried AbsoluteLink but '?tab=2' is left out.

Comment: Are you using SS 2.4 or 3.1 ?

Comment: I am using SilverStripe 3.+, I found this solution via SS forum  http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/72918

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the complete URL of the current page you can for example combine AbsoluteLink with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']:

```
$url = $page->AbsoluteLink() . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

or you build the link with the PHP environment variables:

```
$url = ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Generally a look at the environment variables of PHP can help a lot. You can just display all of the environment information by running this simple script on your web server:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php